# Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error after compiling Linux kernel

Tags: linux

I am a new Linux user and feel confused about one question.
After compiling the Linux kernel, I tried to run output file (./ping.o in net/ipv4/ping.o for example). 
However, the output of the terminal said

> bash: ./ping.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

After that, I used

> file ping.o

The output is

> ping.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), with
>   debug_info, not stripped

And my computer is the same architecture as the file, which is x86_64

> uname -m
>
> x86_64

Could anyone help me for this question, or give me a hint?
I will be every happy if I could get the reason.
Thank you every much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple problems here:

- Linux kernel is not supposed to be run from Linux command line. It is supposed to be run from privileged mode to start operating system.
- .o files are so-called `object files`. They contain compiled code and references to other symbols (other code), but not the referenced code itself. This means you can't run object file as it is only one piece of a puzzle. First you need to link all of object files together. Which is, of course, done while building Linux, the result was called `vmlinuz` some time ago, maybe they renamed it once more.
- Even if you were to link ping.o, it probably lacks entry point (`main()` function). There is some code but there's no clue how to run it and what to pass as its inputs. `main` function provides all that.

I might be able to help you more if you elaborate *why* you are doing what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, I understand more after reading your answer.